# Изменение значение средствами jquery

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как средствами jquery можно изменить значение poid, которое при загрузке страницы задает php, нужно что бы после отправки формы ajax методом, менялся poid на какой нибудь другой из хэша. Помогите пожалуйста если это возможно. Заранее Спасибо!

```
<form  id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajd.php?poid=<?php echo $post_id ?>'>
```

Comment: @LovelyCat скажите, как можно умудриться не знать таких элементарных вещей, сидя на этом форуме уже почти полтора года и задав полсотни вопросов по phph и js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$('#imageForm').attr('action', 'new value');

Comment: Спасибо, не подскажите, еще, как можно выдернуть из php при помощи jquery новый хэш что бы его туда запихнуть ?

Comment: Не понял вопрос, распишите чуть подробнее.

Comment: Как методами jquery сделать md5 хэш что бы лишний раз не обращаться к php ?! Хэш из времени например в секундах ?

Comment: У jQuery нет встроенных методов по генерации md5 hash, однако можно дополнить такой функционал плагином, например вот этим https://github.com/placemarker/jQuery-MD5